# Solr: strip punctuation before index

Tags: solr, indexing, punctuation, filterfactory

I am having a problem with striping punctuation from the solr index
When the punctuation sign follow right after a word then this word is not indexed properly.

For example: if we index "hello, John", the asset won't be found by keyword "hello" while there will be no issue if we remove comma after word "hello".

Is there any FilterFactory that suppose to strip punctuation? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory` to strip beginning and trailing punctuation with this:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
    pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$"
    replacement="$1"/>
```

And if you wanted to strip all punctuation at the beginning and end, except (for example) the dollar-sign in front of a word, you could use this:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
    pattern="^[\p{Punct}&&[^$]]*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$"
    replacement="$1"/>
```

Comment: I believe Mason's edit changed this answer too radically. He ought to have added another answer.

Comment: @CorayThan How is it too radical of a change? I slightly tweaked the regex on claytron's original answer since capturing the punctuation only to throw it away later is unnecessary, and then added an example of how to tweak that regex further if one wishes to strip all punctuation EXCEPT for a specific character... something that could be pretty useful. Neither seem like a completely different answer to me, so it doesn't seem right to post it as such.

Answer (score 6):

This is done with the WordDelimiterFilterFactory. Set generateWordParts=1.

There is also the [PatternTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory) that could be used, but I have never tried it.

Comment: For people with edge cases like mine: The generateWordParts=1 will normally work, but if you're doing what I'm doing, it won't: I'm using the `types` attribute of WDFF to map . and $ to ALPHA, so that I can match terms like `$10.00`. This has the negative side effect of causing prefix and suffix periods being included as part of the word. So in my case the answer by @claytron may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use PatternReplaceFilterFactory

```
<!-- remove punctuation -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(\p{Punct}*)(.*?)(\p{Punct}*)$" replacement="$2"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

...